# SSRS: Call a dataset from a textbox with a parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a dataset that is a query which has a where clause like this 'where field1 like @parameter1' parameter1 is a string defined as a parameter in the dataset1. I have various text boxes that calls the dataset with expressions like =First(Fields!field_xx, "Dataset1"). For each textbox I like to specify a different value for @parameter1 when it calls the "dataset1". How can I modify the expression in each textbox as to call the "dataset1" from each of them with a hardcoded value for @parameter1

the query:

```
SELECT     TOP (1) job.job_id, job.originating_server, job.name, job.enabled, job.description, job.start_step_id, job.category_id, job.owner_sid, job.notify_level_eventlog, 
                      job.notify_level_email, job.notify_level_netsend, job.notify_level_page, job.notify_email_operator_id, job.notify_netsend_operator_id, job.notify_page_operator_id, 
                      job.delete_level, job.date_created, job.date_modified, job.version_number, job.originating_server_id, job.master_server, activity.session_id, activity.job_id AS Expr1, 
                      activity.run_requested_date, activity.run_requested_source, activity.queued_date, activity.start_execution_date, activity.last_executed_step_id, 
                      activity.last_executed_step_date, activity.stop_execution_date, activity.job_history_id, activity.next_scheduled_run_date, steps.step_name
FROM         sysjobs_view AS job INNER JOIN
                      sysjobactivity AS activity ON job.job_id = activity.job_id INNER JOIN
                      sysjobsteps AS steps ON activity.last_executed_step_id = steps.step_id AND activity.job_id = steps.job_id
WHERE     (job.name LIKE 'Actual Job Name')
ORDER BY activity.start_execution_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call a dataset with different parameters in the same report execution. Every execution and rendering of the report fetches each dataset only once.

This means that you have to construct your dataset in a way so that it returns all the data you need, to populate each of your textboxes.

Depending on your data model, you may want to add more columns to your dataset, or return the data in multiple rows. If you have multiple rows, then you can use the `Lookup` function in an expression, to filter out the row in each individual textbox.

Perhaps if you elaborated a little more on what your report should look like, and what the structure of the data you are fetching is, it would be possible to give a better answer to how to solve your problem with a single dataset.

Comment: I added the actual query I replicated a hundred times for each dataset :)

Comment: You should just let the query return multiple rows in a single dataset, one row for each job, and then use the Lookup-function as noted above to filter out the row you need in each textbox. Or BETTER YET: Use a TABLIX - that way, you only have to create one textbox :-)

Comment: I suggest you create a new question and tag it with [sql] and [sql-server] - someone will quickly help you to get what you want from that query.